# how to write this code in angular14 syntax?

Tags: angular, typescript

this is the code:
`

```
constructor(obj?: any) {
    this.id= obj && obj.id||null;
    this.title= obj && obj.title          || null;
    this.description= obj && obj.description    || null;
    this.thumbnailUrl= obj && obj.thumbnailUrl   || null;
    this.videoUrl= obj && obj.videoUrl       ||
                         `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${this.id}`;
  }
```

`
it doesnt work in angular 14

i didnt try anything

Comment: what error you get? Provide more information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is you wont be using constructors like that.  You should be using the constructor to inject services and providers.  I'm pretty sure what your trying to accomplish can be done with ngOnInit and a method inside the class.  If you need them to be assigned earlier than when ngOnInit, you can still put stuff in the constructor, just you cannot initialize them there.
What you want to do is initialize the variables before the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply remove the ***obj &&***

try as below

```
constructor(obj: any = {}) {
  this.id = obj.id || null;
  this.title = obj.title || null;
  this.description = obj.description || null;
  this.thumbnailUrl = obj.thumbnailUrl || null;
  this.videoUrl = obj.videoUrl || `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${this.id}`;
}
```